# Mongo indexing fields for optimizing aggregation of big data

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b7d232cb4ddc345c3bcef4"),
    "user_device_id" : ObjectId("59b7d21017c8a62f3a40c0bf"),
    "generated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-12T12:24:48.182Z"),
    "game_id" : ObjectId("59b683d4dd30770001513c75"),
    "device_type" : "iPhone 8 android sdk",
    "session_duration": 1000, /* in milliseconds */
    "device_os" : "iOS android sdk",
    "event_type" : "level_increase" /* new_user, game_session, ....*/
} // events collection

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b7d21017c8a62f3a40c0bf"),
    "generated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-12T12:24:48.182Z"),
    "game_id" : ObjectId("59b683d4dd30770001513c75"),
    "device_type" : "iPhone 8 android sdk",
    "device_os" : "iOS android sdk"
} // user_devices collection
```

I have a '**events**' collection which has the similar above structure. I am having **mongo** as a **big data analytics platform** so to get the optimum speed for aggregation query in milliseconds or if not then in couple of seconds which fields should I index any idea. The total amount of documents will probably be around 10-100s of billions.

Aggregation query will be basically between two dates which are user retention per game, average user session per game, total user per game, query based on **device_type** or **device_os** per game.

ATM I have date field indexed.

Here is the example of a Day 1 user retention query:

```
UserDevice.aggregate(
        [
            {$match: {generated_at: {$gte: first_date, $lt: end_date}, game_id: "some game_id"}},
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "events",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "user_device_id",
                    as: "event_docs"
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { day: { $dayOfMonth: {$add: ["$generated_at", 1000*3600*24*1]}}, month: {$month: {$add: ["$generated_at", 1000*3600*24*1]}},  year: { $year: {$add: ["$generated_at", 1000*3600*24*1]} } }, total_users: {$sum: 1},
                    returned_users: {
                        $sum: {
                            $cond: { if: { $eq: [
                                    {
                                        $filter: {
                                            input: "$event_docs",
                                            as: "ed",
                                            cond: {
                                                $and: [
                                                    {$eq: [{ $dayOfMonth: {$add: ["$generated_at", 1000*3600*24*1]}}, { $dayOfMonth: "$$ed.generated_at" }]},
                                                    {$eq: [{ $month: {$add: ["$generated_at", 1000*3600*24*1]}}, { $month: "$$ed.generated_at" }]},
                                                    {$eq: [{ $year: {$add: ["$generated_at", 1000*3600*24*1]}}, { $year: "$$ed.generated_at" }]},
                                                    {$ne: ["$$ed.event_type", "new_user"]}
                                                ]

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, []
                                ]}, then: 0, else: 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $sort: {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1}
            }
            ]).exec(function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var latency = Date.now() - startTime;

                console.log("RETENTION RESULTS", JSON.stringify(results), "| latency:", latency,"ms");
            });
```

Mongo Version: **3.4.7**

Comment: Rather than describing your aggregation pipeline in words, can you include an actual example of the aggregation query as well as your specific version of MongoDB?

Comment: @Stennie yes I updated the question with query example and a mongo version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all indexes are used in aggregation in full only from MongoDB 3.2.

> Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, indexes can cover an
>   aggregation pipeline. In MongoDB 2.6 and 3.0, indexes could not cover
>   an aggregation pipeline since even when the pipeline uses an index,
>   aggregation still requires access to the actual documents.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

Make sure you have this version or newer.
In general, you can create indexes for all fields that are in `$match` section of your queries.

I would also suggest go through ‘Aggregation Pipeline Optimization’ section of mongodb  docs. It might be helpful
For ex. you can use `explain` option  to see how query is executed and understand if it can be optimized.

Comment: "indexes are used in aggregation only from MongoDB 3.2" is definitely not the case! For example, see [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/applications/aggregation/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes) in the MongoDB 2.2 manual (the release series that introduced the Aggregation Framework). There are indeed considerations on index usage depending on agg stages and version of MongoDB so it is worth reviewing the [Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) section of the documentation relevant to your server version.

Comment: @Stennie - you're right there were indexes in previous versions, but they did not work "as we would expect". Please, check updated post - I've added a quote and link to documentation.

Comment: Thanks @rumoku, your response makes more sense with the extra context you added. Covered queries are definitely useful depending on the aggregation pipeline. OP has updated their question with an actual example that may help in terms of providing relevant suggestions.